# How to rename index path in routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How to rename `index` path only?

*routes.rb*

```
resources :tasks, :except => [:create] do 
 collection do 
  .............. 
 end 

 member do 
  ............. 
 end 
end
```

instead of `/tasks` in **URL** I need `/trigger` or even `/tasks/trigger` will do, im on `rails3`.

I tried

1.

```
collection do 
'/', to: 'tasks#trigger' 
end
```

and

2.

```
resources :tasks, :except => [:create] do
   get '/task', to: 'task#trigger', as: task_index
end
```

both throw up `errors`.

any ideas?

Comment: Is your index method in task's controller named as 'trigger'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For URL like '/trigger' add to routes.rb:

```
get 'trigger' => 'tasks#index'
```

For URL like '/tasks/trigger' modify routes.rb:

```
resources :tasks, :except => [:create] do 
  collection do
    get 'trigger' => 'tasks#index'
  end
end
```

If  your index method in task's controller named as 'trigger, `'tasks#index'` is replaced by `'tasks#trigger'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your own index route then you need to do two things

1- you need to disable index path created by resources

2- Define your own path whatever you want.

As per your requirement you want to make index route as '/trigger'.

Following is the solution.

```
get 'trigger' => 'tasks#index'
resources :tasks, :except => [:create, :index] do 
 collection do 
  .............. 
 end 

 member do 
  ............. 
 end 
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can elaborate or explain your codes?

Answer (score 1):

Just restraint index route from being generated in your resources call:

```
resources :tasks, :except => [:create, :index]
```

And then do your own custom route. For **'/trigger'**:

```
 get 'trigger', to: 'task#trigger', as: 'trigger
```